# Convert timestamp to date in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How can I return from the database all rows with a timestamp converted to a date `(d-m-Y H:i)`, using the `all()` method?

It's not `created_at` or `updated_at` column, it's custom attribute, call it `birthday` if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to convert the date within the `query`, if `mysql` is being used as your database then you may use a raw query like this:

```
// Assumed my_birthday is like 1255033470
$raw = DB::raw("date_format(from_unixtime(my_birthday),'%b %d, %Y %l:%i %p') as dob");
$result = Model::get(array('id', 'username', $raw));
```

You may write it within single line:

```
$result = Model::get(array('id', 'username', DB::raw("...")));
```

Comment: Sorry, but this will not work. You will always get in output date 01.01.1970.

Comment: Why not ? what is your filed, timestamp ? Something like `1255033470` ?

Comment: It start from 1394902800. Every date output as 01-01-1970. (I have modified your example to %d-%m-%Y)

Comment: Check the updated answer, change `'my_birthday'` to `my_birthday`.

Comment: raw query method will have drawbacks?

Answer (score 9):

timestamp columns like `created_at` are being parsed first. the *U* is simply the timestamp format. you can return your own format. for other formats see [date docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

edit: as stated in my comment, `getDateFormat()` is for both ways (insert, selects). your best bet would be using format inside the model. example:

```
public function getMyBirthdayAttribute()
{
    return $this->my_birthday->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

use `$model->my_birthday` to call the attribute.

```
// controller
$posts = Post::all();

// within sometemplate.blade.php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    my formatted date: {{ $post->my_birthday }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's not created_at, updated_at. It's custom data, does it make any difference?

Comment: Any way if i try: Y-m-d H:i:s, it still returns timestamp.

Comment: i see. `getDateFormat` is for both inserts and selects. if i understand you correctly, you just want an easy way of formatting datetime formats from the database. gonna update my answer accordingly.

Comment: How can i use $model->my_birthday within all method? I'm really sorry but i can't it make work, or i get an error or timestamp.

Comment: it's just a basic property on the model. i added a new example for a better understanding.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for that. But if i want to return json response? I'm not able to do foreach.

Answer (score 8):

The better way to manage dates with Laravel IMHO is to use the `getDates` accessor that is build into Laravel.

All you need to do is to set a method on your Model as such.

```
public function getDates()
{
    return [
        'my_birthday',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
}
```

This will return a `Carbon` object. Carbon is insanely awesome for manipulating dates.

It is what Laravel does by default to created_at and updated_at.

You can then do things like:

```
$my_birthday->diffForHumans()  // 2 Days ago
$my_birthday->format('d.m.Y')  // 20.02.1979
```

There are tons of helpers here for you. Check out the Carbon docs: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Definitely worth learning. It might not be easy to understand for a beginner. However, I would advise you take a look and get your head around it. It will change your life - Dates can be a pain!

Comment: {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($birthday->created_at)->format('d-m-Y H:i') }}

Answer (score 2):

Just place this on your code
$post it depend on what you create

```
$post ->created_at->format('d.m.Y')
```